# CStdIOFile infinite loop error while reading a perl file

Tags: winapi, mfc

How to read Unix formatted EOL perl files in a MFC application using CStdioFile class? when I am reading the file using GetPostion() and ReadLine() methods it is going into infinite loop. any help pls...

Comment: Much more detail is needed before we can attempt to answer your question. Please refer to the 'How to Ask' section of the help for an idea of what's needed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no `CStdioFile` class in the Windows API. What library are you using?

Comment: I am using MFC library of microsoft. Below is the link for CStdioFile Please go through it.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a499td6y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use CStdioFile like this:

```
 CStdioFile f;
 CString sData;
 CString sLine;

 if( f.Open( _T("C:\MyFiles\MyFile.txt"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText ))
 {
    while (f.ReadString(sLine))
    {
      sData += sLine;
    }
    f.Close();
 }
```